# How can I get yarn to use the right version of Node?

Tags: npm, javascript, signal

I am new to Node, JavaScript etc. and want to try messing with the code of [Signal](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop). For this I need [a specific version of Node](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/blob/development/.nvmrc). I did this (on Ubuntu 16.04) using the following procedure:

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.2.1/node-v8.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo mkdir -p /opt/nodejs
sudo tar -xvzf node-v8.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/nodejs/
cd /opt/nodejs/
sudo mv node-v8.2.1-linux-x64 8.2.1
sudo ln -s 8.2.1 current
sudo ln -s /opt/nodejs/current/bin/node /bin/node
mode -v
```

I then installed NPM:

```
sudo apt install npm
```

I then started working through [the setup steps for Signal](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md):

```
sudo npm install --global yarn
sudo yarn install --frozen-lockfile
sudo yarn grunt
```

When I run this last command, I see that an incorrect version of Node is being used and then encounter an error:

```
yarn run v1.5.1
warning You are using Node "4.2.6" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
error An unexpected error occurred: "Couldn't find a package.json file in \"/opt/nodejs\"".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/opt/nodejs/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: How on earth did this get over 1,000 views in a matter of seconds?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you have `nvm` (Node Version Manager) installed and that it is being exported properly from your `.bashrc` file.

If you already have nvm installed, you can change the version to the node version you'd like by running `nvm use v14.18.1`

If you're using WSL or WSL2, this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl) should help you set it up. However, if you're using actual Ubuntu nvm should already be set up in the home directory in the `.bashrc` file.